# How to list Directories from Frida?

Tags: javascript, android, reverse-engineering, frida

Running from Frida Gadget I have very limited access to the file system and therefore would like to poke around and understand where I have read access to.
Any idea's on how to print the content of directories?

I've tried reading the Frida documentation; there's nothing.
I expect a JS function as follows :

`function listdir(path) {}`

That implements the solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `java.io.File` object as follows:

```
Java.perform(function(){
    function listdir(path) {
        var dir = Java.use('java.io.File').$new(path).listFiles()
        if (!dir) {
            console.log("Can't access or dir empty");
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
                console.log(dir[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    listdir('/data/user/0/<SOME_APP>/databases/');
})
```